# Problema em compilar código no Keras

Tags: python-3.x, redes-neurais, deep-learning, keras

Eu estava criando um classificador simples em Keras no Python3, ma seu fico recebendo a mesma mensagem de erro:

> RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.

Segue o código:

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Activation, MaxPooling2D, Convolution2D
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


class OwnClassificator:
    def __init__(self):

# Preparando os dados de treino

        self.preparing_train = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /225, 
           shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

        self.data_train = self.preparing_train.flow_from_directory(
           directory=r'C:Meu diretório', 
           target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=15,
           class_mode='binary')

# Preparando os dados de validação

        self.validation_preparing = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. /225, 
           shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)

        self.data_validation =self.validation_preparing.flow_from_directory(
            directory=r'C:meu diretório', target_size=(200, 200), batch_size=10, class_mode='binary')

    # **************************************************************************************************************

    self.model = keras.Sequential()


    self.model.add(Convolution2D((32, 3, 3), kernel_size=15))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    self.model.add(Convolution2D((32, 3, 3), kernel_size=15))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    self.model.add(Convolution2D((32, 3, 3), kernel_size=15))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

    # **************************************************************************************************************

    self.model.add(Flatten())
    self.model.add(Dense(64))
    self.model.add(Activation('relu'))
    self.model.add(Dropout(0.5))

    self.model.add(Dropout(1))
    self.model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

    # **************************************************************************************************************

    self.model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

    self.model.fit_generator(generator=self.data_train, steps_per_epoch=554 // 15, epochs=80,
                validation_data=self.data_validation)

    self.model.save_weights('models/simple_CNN.h5')


    # **************************************************************************************************************

    self.img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(r'C:meu diretorio',
                                                  target_size=(200, 200))
    self.predict = self.model.predict(self.img)
    print(f'PREDICTION: {self.predict}')


FirstModel = OwnClassificator()
```

Answer (score 1):

Esse código está mal indentado e não executa. Em python, isso é um erro mortal.

A primeira coisa que você precisa fazer é arrumar indentação. Eu recebo o erro:

`NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Em segundo lugar, para modelos simples, uma implementação baseada em classes não é a mais inteligente.

Siga a [Zen do Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

- Flat is better than nested.

Tente fazer um script raso apenas com o código que você quer executar. Usando variáveis locais ao script.

Use [este exemplo](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) keras como referência. Consulte também a documentação do [flow_from_directory](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).